# How to sort ENUM field order and set relation table condition to PostgreSQL with TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, enums, typeorm

About Enum filed sort, if use MySQL, this way can sort ENUM field order:

```sql
ORDER BY FIELD(code, 'USD','CAD','AUD','BBD','EUR', 'GBP')
```

For PostgreSQL, maybe there isn't a built-in method, but this way works:

```sql
SELECT * FROM currency_codes
  ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN code='USD' THEN 1
    WHEN code='CAD' THEN 2
    WHEN code='AUD' THEN 3
    WHEN code='BBD' THEN 4
    WHEN code='EUR' THEN 5
    WHEN code='GBP' THEN 6
    ELSE 7
  END,name;
```

How to do it with TypeORM? I didn't find a `field` function there.

About set relation table condition to find method, I tried this way below(`andWhere` block)

```js
const [items, total] = await this.findAndCount({
  where: {
    enable: true,
  },
  join: {
    alias: 'posts',
    innerJoinAndSelect: {
      category: 'posts.category',
    },
  },
  //andWhere: {
  //  'category.post_id': In(params.postId), // It doesn't work
  //},
  order: { CASE WHEN code='USD' THEN 1 ... }, // It doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you can create a [type enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html), then define a column of that type and sort on the column.

> The ordering of the values in an enum type is the order in which the
> values were listed when the type was created. All standard comparison
> operators and related aggregate functions are supported for enums.

So you can:

```
create type currency_type as enum ( 'USD','CAD','AUD','BBD','EUR', 'GBP'); 

create table payments( id            integer generated always as identity
                                             primary key
                     , cust_id       integer
                     , currency_code currency_type
                     ) ;

select * 
  from payments
 order by currency_code;
```

Further if the enum is altered to add new values the sorting automatically adjusts to the additions. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YQE3qne1))

Sorry but I do not know TypeORM so cannot provide that, but using the enum after creating it should not be difficult, creating it possibly.